# Assigning datetime variable to a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a datetime variable `date_var=datetime(2020,09,11,0,0,0 )` and i am trying to populate a dataframe column for each row with this value. So i did something like `df['Time']=date_var` first this show 'Time' field datatype as datetime64 [ns] and not datetime and this populates Time field with value `2020-09-11` instead of `2020-09-11 00:00:00`. Am i doing something incorrect ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've done nothing wrong.  The fact that it prints as the date without time is just a convention in Pandas for simpler output.  You can use `df['Time'].dt.strftime('%F %T')` if you want the column printed with the time part as well.

Storing datetimes as the Pandas type (`datetime64[ns]`) is better than storing them as the Python type, because it is more efficient to manipulate (e.g. to add offsets to all of them).

Comment: But i need to have it as datetime type and not datetime64[ns] , how can that be done ?

Comment: @Invictus: Use `df['Time'].to_pydatetime()` to convert the Series of Pandas datetimes into plain Python datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

date_var = datetime.datetime(2020,9,11,0,0,0)
df['Time'] = date_var.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```